# Attach An Element When A PDF href Is Opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am testing something, and am not entirely sure it's possible. I have a basic href for an external pdf. I would like to attach a dynamic element to it, say a div and h1 tag for now.

```
<a href="https://osm.hpi.de/teaching/profSem/statistics101.pdf" onclick="createElements()">View</a>

<script>
function createElements(){
   var div = $(document.createElement('div'));
            div.innerHTML = '<h1 id="myTitle" class="back-button" alt="custom-title">';
            $('#myTitle').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'z-index': '99',
                'top': '16px',
                'left': '12px',
                'width': '11%',
            });
}
</script>
```

Basically, when the external href is opened, I want to add attach an h1 tag on that document. Not sure if that's possible, however, testing the waters for now. The code above doesn't seem to work, but would appreciate feedback to see if this can be done with plain vanilla javascript/jquery.

Comment: 'I want to add attach an h1 tag on that document' Do you mean the PDF? If so that's not possible. If you mean that you want to add the `h1` to the current page, that's also not possible as the current page has been unloaded as you sent the user to the PDF file already.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot affect a document that is not yet opened. For this to work, your javascript code would need to be inside the PDF but since browsers treat PDF content differently (as they should), it will never be executed. In short, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I figured that was the case, just decided to throw it out there just incase. My next option is to just load it in an IFrame

Comment: Yes, that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your href will always send the user to a PDF-viewer of the browser and you'll lose control over that.

If you want to have an element visible above or over the PDF file, you can maybe use a "template page" where you have your HTML element and a fullscreen iFrame with a src that points to the PDF file.

This will render the browser's PDF viewer in that iFrame winthin your template page.

Ex.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <!-- Your element here (you can make this absolute to make it lay over the pdf file etc.. -->
  </div>
  <iframe src=".../.pdf" style="width:100vw;height:100vh">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need jQuery at all. I would do something like this (notice I leave the div empty beforehand):

```
<a href="https://osm.hpi.de/teaching/profSem/statistics101.pdf" onclick="createElements()">View</a>
<div id="myDiv"></div>

function createElements(){
   var text = document.createElement("h1");
   text.innerHTML ="MY heading";
   document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(text);
}
```